# this.$vuetify.goTo(0) not working inside v-navigation-drawer in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

This my code:

```
<template>
   ....
   <v-navigation-drawer app absolute width="340" permanent>

    ....
     <v-btn fab dark fixed bottom left color="primary" @click="$vuetify.goTo(0)">
        <v-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</v-icon>
     </v-btn>
    ...
   <v-navigation-drawer>

<template>
```

When I click the button as shown in the code, it should scroll to the top of the drawer. But it doesn't. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you think it should scroll to the top ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `container`, which is one of the [`options`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/scroll/#usage) for scroll. If you are not providing this, vuetify won't know to place it on your nav drawer.

Add a ref to your nav drawer:

```html
<v-navigation-drawer app absolute width="340" permanent ref="myNavDrawer">
```

You can assign the element in your script, so that we can refer to it in `goTo`:

```js
mounted() {
  this.navDrawerContent = 
   this.$refs['myNavDrawer'].$el.querySelector('div.v-navigation-drawer__content');
}
```

Then for your button, pass `0` as you did, but add the `container`:

```html
<v-btn ... @click="$vuetify.goTo(0, { container: navDrawerContent } )">
```

**A [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/AJT82/pen/OJMWNJZ) for your reference.**